# Вывод на печать

Tags: php, javascript, php7

На сервере находится шаблон в формате *doc*, в шаблоне имеется `n` строк.

В определенный текст по закладке (к примеру), нужно добавить текст (средствами **php** или **javascript**). Возможно ли реализовать, если да то желательно приведите пример?

Возможно есть другие способы реализации? Но шаблон должен храниться именно на сервере (формат шаблона не имеет значение *doc*, *xls* и др.)

Comment: С чем именно возникли трудности?

Comment: К сожалению, нет опыта работы php+word и javascript+word. И желательно на каком нибудь примере посмотреть. И основной момент, что шаблон есть, а не формируем с нуля, в шаблон необходимо вставить свои данные в определенные места, в том числе и таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это заполнение шаблона, то могу посоветовать [phpWord](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=phpword).
Создаете документ, на тех местах, где у вас данные, удаляете их и вставляете имена переменных в виде `${variable}`. Потом в коде обрабатываем шаблон.

```
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('example.docx'); //шаблон
$document->setValue('variable', 'string'); //подстановка значения
$document->save('ready.docx'); //имя заполненного шаблона для сохранения
```

---

Также будут проблемы с кириллицей, для решения проблемы надо перейти в `PHPWord/Template.php` и найти там функцию `setValue`. Там удаляем или закомментируем строку `$replace = utf8_encode($replace);`

Comment: А при заполнении таблицы, все так же только в цикле?